# How to run a custom script on the launch of IDLE on Mac?

Tags: python, shell, python-idle

When I click IDLE icon, IDLE shell opens! It looks like this

[Python IDLE shell just after startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5r8J.png)

So, there is a script that runs whenever I launch IDLE, and this scripts has commands that print

"Python 3.8.5 (v3.8.5:580fbb018f, Jul 20 2020, 12:11:27) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
".

1- Is it possible to locate this file on my computer(Mac) and edit it ? if yes, how?
2- Is it possible to add another separate script to run at startup ? if yes, how?
3- I initially wanted some easy way to clean the shell, the easiest way was to define a function like this 
def cls(): print('\n' * 44) 
I don't want to write it whenever the shell was restarted. any other solution for this problem will be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *Currently*, the startup script is `idlelib/pyshell.py`.  You can edit it in IDLE (make a backup first), by loading it with `File >= Load module` and entering `idlelib.pyshell` in the dialog.
2. See Command Line Usage in the IDLE doc, available in IDLE as `Help >= IDLE Help`.  In particular, "-s   run $IDLESTARTUP or $PYTHONSTARTUP first, in shell window", where `XYZSTARTUP` is an environmental variable.